# Windows phone 8 make async method behave like its sync

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, asynchronous

I am new to async programming and I am wondering if you can fake c# async methods to make it work like its sync? Or if you can make it wait for it to complete before executing another method?

In my case :

```
await Speak("Do you want me to call 123 ?");
   if (isComplete)
       {
          PhoneCallTask phone = new PhoneCallTask();
           phone.PhoneNumber = "123";
            phone.Show();

        } 
await Speak("blabla");
```

isComplete is global boolean..

here is Speak method:

```
private async Task Speak(string text)
    {
    SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    await synth.SpeakTextAsync(text);
    isComplete = true;
    }
```

It says first text, than shows dialog.. after dialog is cloes it crashes..

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Purpose of the async methods are to work asynchronously.

Comment: I am using Text to speech, and then showing some call dialog, and when i show call dialog app crashes, because this dialog breaks speech because its async.. thats why i would like to wait for speech to complete and then run call dialog..

Comment: Oh ok. Are you using SpeechSynthesizer?

Comment: yes, I am using SpeechSynthesizer

Comment: Ok see my answer below

Comment: What's the error message you are getting?

Comment: The text assoicated with this error code could not be found
 a speech operation was aborted by a system call for example fast app switching or an incoming phone call

Comment: What's the emulator you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `await` keyword

See following example taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207057(v=vs.105).aspx)

```
// Declare the SpeechSynthesizer object at the class level.
SpeechSynthesizer synth;

// Handle the button click event.
private async void SpeakFrench_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // Initialize the SpeechSynthesizer object.
  synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

  // Query for a voice that speaks French.
  IEnumerable<VoiceInformation> frenchVoices = from voice in InstalledVoices.All
                     where voice.Language == "fr-FR"
                     select voice;

  // Set the voice as identified by the query.
  synth.SetVoice(frenchVoices.ElementAt(0));

  // Count in French.
  await synth.SpeakTextAsync("un, deux, trois, quatre");
}
```

Comment: I am actually doing this.. SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        await synth.SpeakTextAsync(text);
and after that I call phoneCallTask.Show() and dialog pops up, and when I close it, exception is thrown and it says that speech has been disrupted by a phone call...

Comment: I have added boolean at the end of speak method, and now speech is executed before call dialog.. but however, when i call dialog is closed, and i want to go back to speech, app crashes